# Filtering the Products of my Caddie with JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

My entity `Caddie`contains a `@OneToMany` relation with its `Product`

```
@Entity
public class Caddie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int id;

    @OneToMany
    @OrderBy("price")
    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class Product{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    String name;
}
```

I want all products from my caddie that are more expensive than 2$.
I have tried many things including this one :

```
String query = " SELECT p FROM Product p "
                    + "JOIN Caddie c "
                    + "WHERE c.id = 1 "
               + "AND p MEMBER OF c.products AND p.price > :price";
```

Unfortunately, I have two *Path* there. Trying :

```
String query = " SELECT c.products FROM Caddie c "
                + "JOIN c.products prods "
                + "WHERE c.id = 1 AND prods.price > :price";
```

I don't have the objects I wanted. 
I could create an Entity named CaddieProduct, but I would like something cleaner.

Comment: Can't you define @ManyToOne Caddie in your Product and then **SELECT p FROM Product p JOIN Caddie c WHERE c.id = 1 AND p.price > :price** should work

Comment: This would surely work but is not *domain driven*. It may create chaos at other time.

Comment: Alternatively you can call yourQuery.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Product.class))